# Why can't I see the sudoer permissions for another user in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, sudo, administration

I am very used to using `sudo -l -U <user>` to check another user's sudo capabilities but since version 18.04 I can no longer see this. It always comes back blank.

Is there some special setting I need to tweak?

---

#### Update

The user I am executing this with has the following permissions

```
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
    (ALL : ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

as shown after executing `sudo -l`

---

#### Update2

the return code when I execute the command is `1`

```
$ sudo -l -U other_user
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Are you sure the checking user has the `ALL` sudo privilege?

Comment: Yes. I added the update for clarity

Comment: Do you say that the sudo -l -U command returns no output? What about the return code? (`echo $?`). The command should display something. Can you try once more and [edit] your post by adding the command AND its output?

Answer (score 0):

The man page for `sudo` describes the `-U` option like this:

```
-U user, --other-user=user

    Used in conjunction with the -l option to list the privileges for user
    instead of for the invoking user. The security policy may restrict
    listing other users' privileges. The sudoers policy only allows root or
    a user with the ALL privilege on the current host to use this option.
```

This option has not changed since at least Ubuntu 14.04. So, the user who checks this need to have `ALL` privilege on the system.

Comment: Yes. I added the update for clarity

Comment: Is it possible that because the user I am using is logging in remotely to check on a local user, that this permission is restricted?

Comment: I tested that. It makes no difference..

Comment: Added what you asked for. I am tempted to look at the system logs again. Maybe I'm missing something, last time I checked I couldn't find anything relevant in sys nor auth

Comment: Hey, wait a sec. The user I'm trying to check is not a local user. He is defined in an LDAP service on a remote machine. Could this also be related? I use SSS to manage authentication and credential caching

Comment: I can't help you about LDAP, because I do not have a similar environment here. Sorry...